# Remove tags and their content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

How can I remove certain tags AND their content in Rails?

I tried `sanitize` and `strip_tags` but they just remove the tags and leave the content.

```
<%= raw sanitize(@content, :tags => ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p','ul','ol','li','small','b','strong','em','i','u']) %>
```

So if I have this:

```
<script>alert('test js');</script>
<p>Hello world</p>
```

I want to become:

```
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Which at the moment becomes:

```
alert('test js');
<p>Hello world</p>
```

Comment: you only want to remove the tag and content of this tags or you want specific tag ? Maybe you can use [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse specific tags.

Comment: same thing working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanitize has a `remove_contents` option which you can use for this.

From the test code:

```
Sanitize.fragment('foo bar <div>baz<span>quux</span></div>',
  :remove_contents => true
)
#=> 'foo bar   '
```

See the [test example](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/blob/425641797ee44d868c1124734258ea9e83afac1d/test/test_clean_element.rb#L331).

For your case above, you can specify tags you want to remove in the value of `remove_contents`, like this:

```
Sanitize.fragment("<script>alert('test js');</script><p>Hello world</p>",
  remove_contents: ["script"]
)
#=> " Hello world "
```

Alternatively, you can specify the elements you want to keep and remove everything else, like this:

```
html = "<strong>foo</strong><div>bar</div>"
Sanitize.fragment(html,
  elements: ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','p','ul','ol','li','small','b','strong','em','i','u'],
  remove_contents: true
)
#=> "<strong>foo</strong>  "
```

If e.g. you just want to remove tags like `<script>` and leave everything else unchanged, you could do something like this:

```
html = "<strong>foo</strong><script>bar</script><p>baz</p><div>foobar</div>"
Sanitize.fragment(html,
  Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::BASIC, remove_contents: ['script'])
)
#=> "<strong>foo</strong><p>baz</p> foobar "
```

Here note that the content for the last `<div>` remains because it was not included in the `remove_contents` array, but its `<div>` tags are removed (which is how `Sanitize::Config::BASIC` works). Replace `Sanitize::Config::BASIC` by `Sanitize::Config::RELAXED` for less restrictive filtering rules, which would leave the `<div>` tags in this example.

Many other things are possible, although the only documentation I found was [in the code itself](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=remove_contents&type=Code).

Comment: Would it be possible to remove `script` but NOT touch the other HTML? As I'd like to avoid passing all those tags to the element option. Thanks.

Comment: So for your second code block, you'd just have `<p>Hello world</p>`

Comment: Try this: `Sanitize.fragment(html, Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::BASIC, remove_contents: true))`

Comment: Added an example above removing `script` while not touching other stuff.

Comment: You can replace `Sanitize::Config::BASIC` by `Sanitize::Config::RELAXED` for less restrictive filtering, which would leave e.g. `<div>` tags in the last example above.

Comment: RELAXED looks to then ignore what is in the remove_contents option.

Comment: No it doesn't: `Sanitize.fragment("<script>foo</script>", Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::RELAXED, remove_contents: true)) #=> ""`

Comment: When using RELAXED does remove_contents only work with certain tags? As I wanted to remove style tags but I still get them.

Comment: Nothing to do with `RELAXED`. Just pass the tag you want to remove to `remove_contents`: `Sanitize.fragment("<style>foo</style>", Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::RELAXED, remove_contents: ['style'])) #=> ""`

Comment: Not working for me when using `RELAXED`. I still see `script`, `style` and other tags that are in my `@content`.

Comment: `<%= raw Sanitize.fragment(@content, Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::RELAXED, remove_contents: ['style', 'script'])) %>`

Comment: I'm using Sanitize version 4.3.0 and the snipped I just posted works fine for me. I don't know what else I can do to help you.

Comment: I am also using 4.3.0. For some reason when using the merge of the built-in and the remove_contents it ignores whatever I put in the remove_contents.

Comment: Can you try the same code from `rails console` ? i.e. run console and try: `Sanitize.fragment("<style>foo</style>", Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::RELAXED, remove_contents: ['style'])) `.

Comment: Ok, seems you're right, it does remove it with `BASIC` but not with `RELAXED`, probably something to do with parsing the content of the `<style>` tag. However, honestly I think I've answered your original question... I would recommend just using `BASIC` since it's the default anyway.

Comment: From the readme: `[RELAXED] Allows an even wider variety of markup, including images and tables, as well as safe CSS.` So that's why the style stuff doesn't get removed, I guess.

Comment: The problem with BASIC is that also removes h1,h2, h3 etc. So it's no good either.

Comment: Here: `Sanitize.fragment(@content, Sanitize::Config.merge(Sanitize::Config::BASIC, elements: Sanitize::Config::RELAXED[:elements] - ['style'], remove_contents: ['style']))`

Comment: Cool thanks :) That works perfectly! Though it's shame the headers were not included in BASIC by default.